# Как протестировать (unit-тестирования) блок catch на vue в методе компонента с помощью Jest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jest

```
        loginSystem() {
            const role = this.role
            let username = this.login;
            let password = this.password;

            this.$store.dispatch('loginSystem', {username, password, role}).then(() => this.$router.push({name: this.role === 'projects'})).catch(
            (error) => {
                if (error.code === 5) {
                this.showLoginError = true
                }
                if (error.response.status === 401) {
                this.showLoginError = true
                }
                if (error.response.status === 403) {
                this.showLoginError = true
                }

            }
        );

    }
```

Comment: Хм, ну, самый первый приходящий на ум способ - это выбросить все эти исключения сервером, вне зависимости от условий. Конечно, если есть такая возможность

Comment: вот как вызвать его какой метод можно использовать? есть ли пример какой нибудь?

Comment: Если showLoginError ничего не меняет на странице (что было бы странно для переменной со словом 'show'), то Vue Dev Tools в помощь

Comment: меня интересует как в тесте вызывать  error чтобы в catch проверится

Comment: У тебя есть код сервера под рукой?

Comment: Найди обработчик твоего твоего запроса. Выброси оттуда все интересующие тебя исключения, просто, тупо, без лишнего кода. Действующий код закомментируй.

Comment: У меня, правда, такой необходимости не возникало. Обычно воспроизвожу ошибку на стороне клиента.

Comment: нельзя закоментировать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118447/discussion-between---and-radion-dev).